# identifying the primary and secondary keywords in sentense

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, ipython

want to identify the primary and secondary keywords which are having an impact to sentences or comparison between 2 keywords.

below is the example

> India and China has highest population in the world.
>
> travelers are interested in travel Paris instead of Hamburg

in the above example
sentences 1 primary keyword is India and secondary keywords is China
sentences 2 primary keyword is Paris and secondary keywords is hamburg

Comment: Are you just looking for proper nouns in the sentence or is there something else you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: As of now, looking for proper nouns maybe in future this could change.